# GPGS - App crashes when launching Auto Match UI in iOS

Tags: ios, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am integrating Google play game services in our app and am including real-time multiplayer. I am having a problem with the auto match default UI. The app either freezes or will crash upon calling the realtime UI. I call the UI using

```
GPGMultiplayerConfig *config = [[GPGMultiplayerConfig alloc] init];
config.minAutoMatchingPlayers = 1;
config.maxAutoMatchingPlayers = 1;

// Show waiting room UI
[[GPGLauncherController sharedInstance] presentRealTimeWaitingRoomWithConfig:config];
```

I see the same log output before the crash:

```
Connect with retry.getRetryAuthToken(): 1
Token expired. Refreshing.
```

I can call the invites UI or player picker UI just fine using the methods detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/realtimeMultiplayer#handling_invitations%22here%22)

Am I missing something?

Update: This is the Bugsense crash log:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36230dfc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib 0x361d0939 abort + 76
2   libc++abi.dylib 0x353dfbbd __cxa_bad_cast + 0
3   libc++abi.dylib 0x353f9639 <redacted> + 212
4   libobjc.A.dylib 0x35bcff35 <redacted> + 228
5   libc++abi.dylib 0x353f6def <redacted> + 78
6   libc++abi.dylib 0x353f65b1 <redacted> + 0
7   libc++.1.dylib 0x353d8501 _ZNSt3__120__throw_system_errorEiPKc + 180
8   libc++.1.dylib 0x35399fe9 _ZNSt3__118condition_variable15__do_timed_waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEENS_    6chrono10time_pointINS5_12system_clockENS5_8durationIxNS_5ratioILx1ELx1000000000EEEEEEE + 40
9   IOSLauncher 0x0116018b 0x8b000 + 17650059
10  IOSLauncher 0x011e9d9d 0x8b000 + 18214301
11  IOSLauncher 0x010d1b4f 0x8b000 + 17066831
12  IOSLauncher 0x010d219d 0x8b000 + 17068445
13  IOSLauncher 0x0108ccb5 0x8b000 + 16784565
14  IOSLauncher 0x0108cb2b 0x8b000 + 16784171
15  IOSLauncher 0x0108c875 0x8b000 + 16783477
16  IOSLauncher 0x01122151 0x8b000 + 17396049
17  IOSLauncher 0x01121e9b 0x8b000 + 17395355
18  IOSLauncher 0x01125709 0x8b000 + 17409801
19  IOSLauncher 0x0110aa2b 0x8b000 + 17300011
20  IOSLauncher 0x01201be9 0x8b000 + 18312169
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x362afe67 <redacted> + 138
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x362afddb _pthread_start + 118
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x362adb84 thread_start + 8
```

It says it is part of the SIGNAL class if that helps.

Comment: The token is refreshed frequently, and is not an indication of a problem.  Is there more to the log, such as an exception?

Comment: When it freezes, no. When it crashes, I do get something from bugsense but it is not that helpful. I updated the OP with bugsense log.